# Setting value to a double struct pointer

Tags: c

So, I am implementing a linked-list based queue and I put the node information in a structure and I put the head and the tail of the queue in a structure. When I try to add a node, I have to use -> twice, and I ended up getting a segmentation fault error.

Now my code is part of a larger program with user input and multiple options and stuff but I simplified it down for ease.

```
typedef enum statucEnum {CALLED_AHEAD, WAITING} status; 
typedef struct nodeStruct{
    char* name; 
    int groupSize; 
    status inStatus;//in resturant status 
    struct nodeStruct* next;
}Node;

//structure to encapsulate the head of the queue along with the tail 
typedef struct headStruct{
    Node* head; 
    Node* tail;
}Queue; 

void intializeQueue(Queue* queue){
    queue->head = NULL; 
    queue->tail = NULL; 
}

int main(){
    Queue queue; 
    intializeQueue(&queue);
    //program ask what the user wants to do, and it decides to add to the queue
    doAdd(&queue);
}

void doAdd(Queue* queue){
    //usually the program would ask the user to input a age and name 
    int age = 4;
    name = "v";
    Node* newNode; 
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->groupSize = size; 
    newNode->name = name;
    newNode->inStatus = WAITING; 
    addToList(queue, newNode); 
}
```

When I use valgrind, it tells me that the segmentation fault is in this code segment

```
void addToList(Queue* queue, Node* node){   
    printf("Address of parameter: %p", node);
    if (queue->head == NULL){
        queue->head->next = node; \\this is where the error occurs 
        queue->tail->next = node; 
    }else{
        queue->tail->next = node; 
        queue->tail = node; 
    }
}
```

More specifically at the line of queue->head->next = node

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You checked against NULL and then dereferened anyway... did you understand the logic before writing the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you head is NULL then how can you set queue->head->next = node;. First of all set you head value then you can update your head next point. So see following code

```
void addToList(Queue* queue, Node* node){   
    printf("Address of parameter: %p", node);
    if (queue->head == NULL){
        queue->head = node; \\this is where the error occurs 
        queue->tail = node; 

    }else{
        queue->tail->next = node; 
        queue->tail = node; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes because `queue->head` is `NULL`:

```
void addToList(Queue* queue, Node* node){   
    printf("Address of parameter: %p", node);
    /* vvvv HERE */
    if (queue->head == NULL){
        queue->head->next = node; \\this is where the error occurs 
        queue->tail->next = node; 
    }else{
        queue->tail->next = node; 
        queue->tail = node; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a bug in the following part from the `addToList` function.

```
if (queue->head == NULL)
{
    queue->head->next = node; \\this is where the error occurs 
    queue->tail->next = node; 
}
```

As a precondition to the block, `queue->head` is `null`, but in the next line `queue->head` is dereferenced by using `queue->head->next`, which is not going to work.